# create oracle date with time stamp from HH24 string

Tags: oracle, timestamp, string-to-datetime

I have hour in 'HH24' format. For example: `'13:35'` I need to convert this into today's date of '13:35' in the time stamp - `"dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS"`.

To_timeStamp() method returning me the date with timestamp of starting of the month.

It is returning `"01-Jul-2019 13:35:00"`, please help me to get today's date with the exact hour and minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the formatted date with your input and then convert that back to a timestamp:

```
select to_timestamp(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd')||' 13:35', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')
from dual;
```

If that time value is a column in your table, use that instead of the constant value:

```
select to_timestamp(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd')||' '||the_time_column, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')
from your_table;
```